# Enable and disable a click event with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some HTML elements

```
<p class="accordion-header open" id="platform_0" onclick="validateScreens(this)">Platform 0</p>
<p class="accordion-header open" id="platform_1" onclick="validateScreens(this)">Platform 0</p>
<p class="accordion-header open" id="platform_2" onclick="validateScreens(this)">Platform 0</p>
```

I want to remove and restore the click event on this element. My JavaScript code is :

```
function validateScreens(domObj)
{   
  if(some condition)
  {  
    $(domObj).off("click"); // //remove click from  <p> whenever there is a click event
  } else {
    $(domObj).on("click",function() { return true; });// restores the click event      
  }
}
```

It is removing the click event successfully but not restoring it.How to do it.

Comment: what is the some condition?

Comment: Once the click event handler removed, how you can restore the same inside the click event which is never going to call once again as you removed it?

Answer (score 1):

```
<p class="accordion-header open" id="platform_0" onclick="validateScreens(this)">Platform 0</p>
<p class="accordion-header open" id="platform_1" onclick="validateScreens(this)">Platform 0</p>
<p class="accordion-header open" id="platform_2" onclick="validateScreens(this)">Platform 0</p>
<script>
function validateScreens(domObj){   
       if(some condition){  
           $(domObj).on("click" , function( e ){ e.preventDefault(); }); 
     }else{
           $(domObj).on("click",function() {  return true; });
        }
}</script>
```

when **event.preventDefault** method is called  the default action of the event will not be triggered.

Read More on : https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: What's the default action for a `<p>`?

Answer (score 0):

Why not trying different approach of having this check in the event handler itself

```
var allowClick = true;

function validateScreens(domObj) {
    if (some condition) {
        allowClick = true;
    } else {
        allowClick = false;
    }
}

$(domObj).on("click", function() {
    if (allowClick) {
        // Do click logic here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

put it inside same If condition. please try this one:

```
if(some condition)
  {   
     //remove click and restore it
    $(domObj).off("click").on("click",function() { return true; });
  } else {
    // anything else if false      
  }
```